# How to get golang programming tour offline

Tags: go

I wanted to download go-tour offline
how can i get it?
I have tried to use code

```
  go get code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please try to provide an error message when something goes wrong. We can't know what happened if you don't tell us and guessing is frustrating.

Comment: It becomes `go get golang.org/x/tour/gotour`.

Answer (score 9):

If by saying "it doesn't work" you mean that you get error message: `package code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath`, then you [need to setup GOPATH](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH) and then `go get` desired package.

Anyway, here is the complete solution to get GoTour working, assuming you already have Go installed.

```
mkdir go_tour && cd go_tour
export GOPATH=`pwd`
go get code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour
./bin/gotour
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you expand on "it doesn't work"?

```
  $ go get code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour

  $ gotour

2014/03/22 20:02:53 Serving content from /Users/matt/.go/src/code.google.com/p/go-tour
2014/03/22 20:02:53 A browser window should open. If not, please visit http://127.0.0.1:3999
```

No problems for me. Make sure your `$GOPATH` is set correctly and exported in your shell. Check the output of `go env` to confirm.